# Reactive environment outside of render

Tags: reactjs

Parent constantly receives a timestamp update:

```
$("window").on("timeUpdate", function(evt) { this.setState({time: evt.time})});
```

Child wants to use this info.

```
render() {
  return {
    <div>{this.props.time}</div>
  }
}
```

It's very straightforward in this case. However, instead of merely using `time` info inside `render()` I need to do the following.

```
updateSlider() {
  this.state.slider.setValue(this.props.time);
}
```

Inside of `render()`, whenever `this.props.time` is updated by the child's parent, it would be *reactively* updated. However, I am not sure where is the most appropriate place to do `updateSlider()` so it's called everytime `this.props.time` is updated.

Comment: What is `this.state.slider` in you component? Is it another component?

Comment: No it's an object from an external lib: bootstrap-slider.

Comment: Since I don't know how the components are structured, I will post this as a comment instead of an answer. The most suitable place to call `slider.setValue()` is perhaps inside the handler of `timeUpdate` event itself. This makes the function call to depends on `timeUpdate` event instead of `this.props.time`

Comment: If that's not an option, where else would be a better place?

Comment: I have posted it as an answer instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From my comment above) The best place to call `slider.setValue()` is inside the handler of `timeUpdate` event itself. This makes the function call to depends on `timeUpdate` event instead of `this.props.time`.

If that must be handled in the child component (I assume you are migrating an existing app to React), you can use [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops). The documentation states that

> Use this as an opportunity to react to a prop transition before `render()` is called by updating the state using `this.setState()`. The old props can be accessed via `this.props`. Calling `this.setState()` within this function will not trigger an additional render.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` was what I wanted!